# How to send some value to another view controller when i select cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I have two View Controllers: `MainScreenViewController` and `TargetScreenViewController`;

In `MainScreenViewController` I have `UITableView` with custom cells, in `TargetScreenViewController` I have the label which i need change.

I need to get some value, index path for example, and pass it along to `TargetScreenViewController` and change the label based on that value.

I already setup the push segue in Triggered Segues in cell, but how can i pass some value and get it there?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    TargetView *target = [[TargetView alloc]initWithNibName:@"TargetView" bundle:nil];

    NSString *data = @"Success";

    target.incomingData = data;

}
```

in TargetView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mLabel.text = self.incomingData;
}
```

but label is blank =[

Comment: take a look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios5-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this .....

1.create a property in your target view controller .

2.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      targetviewcontroller * obj = create object here .
      obj.property = dataToBeSent ;

      ---------------
}
```

then you will get your data by accessing property

Comment: Does not help =( nothing in `obj.property` after i opened Target View

Comment: can you just NSLog the value self.incomingData , so that we can sure we are getting data or not .

Comment: Sure, here is it: `2013-11-07 12:17:47.858 test_002[9469:a0b] (null)`

Comment: then just put another NSlog in tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath to make sure we are getting desired value or getting null there .

Comment: Here is it `2013-11-07 12:28:18.118 test_002[10065:a0b]  in didSelectRowAtIndexPath Success
2013-11-07 12:28:18.122 test_002[10065:a0b]  in viewDidLoad (null)`

Comment: if i place NSlog in didDeselectRowAtIndexPath it never calls

Comment: i just changed method name .

Comment: if u don't have any problem then send your code to my mail id skriyaz7@gmail.com .i will sort out your problem

Comment: Thanks, i send mail to you!

Comment: just check this link .... i think this will solve your problem    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140679/how-to-send-data-between-view-controllers-storyboard-xcode

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    Class *yourObject=[self.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    TargetView *vc=[[TargetView alloc] initWithNibName:@"TargetView" bundle:nil];

    vc.object=yourObject; //Create a p

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

In your **TargetView**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

   self.lbl.text=self.object.value;

}
```

Comment: Crush if i do this `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a notification and post notification with a object. The object what you need to send to second Controller.