# Not understanding how to pass values between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I already know how to pass values or variables between `UIViewController`. In fact, I've got 2 transitions between 2 + 2 `UIViewController` which work fine, but I've got one which doesn't do it.

I've tried to copy everything but this one doesn't seem to work.

This is how I handle the click to pass to another `UIViewController`:

```
-(void)launchProfile:(int) option {
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Profile" bundle:nil];
    ProfileControllerViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileControllerViewController"];

    [vc passValue:_user];
    [vc passOption:option];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

This is my `ProfileControllerViewController.h`:

```
@interface ProfileControllerViewController : UIViewController

-(void)passValue:(NSDictionary*)user;
-(void)passOption:(int)option;

@property (nonatomic , strong) NSDictionary* user;

// ...

@end
```

`This is my`ProfileControllerViewController.m` (the part where I implement the function

```
@implementation ProfileControllerViewController

int optionSelected = -1;
const int optionChanges = 0;
const int optionComments = 1;

-(void)passOption:(int) option {
    optionSelected = option;
}

- (void) passValue:(NSDictionary *)user_ {
    _user = user_;
}

// ...

@end
```

and when it executes `passValue` or `passOption` the error is:

> 2015-06-27 12:31:51.616 Ch4nge.me[41958:1907763] viewDidAppear
>   2015-06-27 12:31:56.041 Ch4nge.me[41958:1907763] Unknown class _TtC31ProfileControllerViewController31ProfileControllerViewController in Interface Builder file.
>   2015-06-27 12:31:57.102 Ch4nge.me[41958:1907763] -[UIViewController passUser:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb505412c00
>   2015-06-27 12:31:57.107 Ch4nge.me[41958:1907763] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController passUser:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb505412c00'

what could be wrong???

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: From the log,It seem that you forget to set class in the storyboard.Check it

Comment: Perhaps consider defining properties in `ProfileControllerViewController` then setting them within `launchProfile:`. It's essentially the same thing you're doing right now but a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-[UIViewController passUser:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` means that your `vc` variable is not of the type `ProfileControllerViewController`.

Probably you haven't set the class in the XIB or Storyboard, which is why `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` isn't returning the expected type; and instead is returning a default instance of type `UIViewController`.

Comment: Since I've got many errors before, I set Class as `ProfileControllerViewController` but **Module** as ProfileControllerViewController as well (both)... that was the problem... I was very sure the class was set that's why I didn't re-take a look. Thank you very much (Will accept answer when it makes me able to do it :D )

Answer (score 1):

You can use the another option for this error, you may use the segue for this,

Refer the below link for this,

[How to Send data between view controllers StoryBoard Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140679/how-to-send-data-between-view-controllers-storyboard-xcode)

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{

   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueIdentifer"]) //use whatever identifer you have set 

   {

      ProfileControllerViewController *vc = (ProfileControllerViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

      vc.user = dict; //NSDictionary value

      vc.option = 1; //Use whatever integer you want to pass

   }

}
```

And in your `ProfileControllerViewController.h` define  `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary* user;` and `@property (nonatomic, assign) int option;`